# How to make DatePickerDialog select a particular date?

Tags: android

When an `EditText`'s content is empty then the `DatePickerDialog` is showing current date :

```
Calendar calendrier = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(ctxt, evt, calendrier.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendrier.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendrier.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

But I want the `DatePickerDialog` showing a date based on the `EdiText`'s content when this content is not empty. How to do that ?

Comment: How do you take date from edittext. In which format? And what problem you faced while parsing dates.

Comment: You can use [updateDate(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#updateDate%28int,%20int,%20int%29) method of [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html)

Comment: @BBdev make it as an answer please cause it is the simplest way which works !

Comment: @pheromix added as an answer... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can easily do it with 
[updateDate(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#updateDate%28int,%20int,%20int%29) method of [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) where you have to pass the date, month and year as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the format that user puts the date in the `EditText`. For instance, if format is `dd/MM/yyyy` then:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter =
        new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date date = formatter.parse(eddittext.getText().toString());
Calendar calendrier = Calendar.getInstance();
calendrier.setTime(date);

DatePickerDialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(ctxt, evt, calendrier.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendrier.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendrier.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

This assumes that the user puts the data in the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

You can first get the string from your edittext and then convert it to date (check this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/ for convertion.) 
Then get the year,month,day from the date object and pass it to your datepicker when showing picker like this

```
datePicker.init(year, month, day, null);
```

Here you go. Cheers!!

Comment: `init` is not available for `DatePickerDialog` !

Comment: You can use DatePicker as it will be best in your scenario. But if you want to use DatePickerDialog then go with @bigdestroyer's answer!